# Category save not working

Tags: category, magento2.2, upgrade, save

I am trying to update the category using following code.

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

foreach($data as $d) {
    $category->setDataUsingMethod($d['code'], $d['value']);
}

$category->save();
```

`$this->categoryFactory` is object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory`

But the category is not getting updated.

I have checked after reindexation as well, but the category is showing the old data and not the updated data.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because of missing `store id`. 
I am able to update the category using following code.

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$data = $category->getData();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $category->setData($key, $value);
}

$category->setStoreId($storeId);
$category->save();
```

I am not sure at this point why it is necessary and if it is like this then why not Magento picking the admin store as the store id by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have not instantiated `$data` there, and its better to use `setData` rather than `setDataUsingMethod` method. You can use the following code to get the result,

```
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

$data = $category->getData();

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $category->setData($key, $value);
}

$category->save();
```